# How can I determine if AD LDS has been configured

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, ad-lds

I've inherited an environment, and am diagnosing some of the smaller issues I am coming across.

One of these issues, is that an existing AD DC has also had the AD LDS role installed. I don't think it has been configured, which causes server manager to throw errors for manageability. This is documented in the server manager diagnosis blog post from a MS engineer.

Before I remove the role, I want to ensure there is no LDS instance configured that I simply cannot see. Is there a way I can determine if the role is actually in use and is safe to remove?

Answer (score 1):

check if there is any instance listening on any ports.
dsdbutil “li I”

Comment: Thanks. Given that this machine is running normal AD DS, will the NT5DS util not list the AD DS role listening on 389?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the fact the server is already acting as an AD DS domain controller, as that is an important point I did not make clear enough originally.